# Find all real numbers k such that $||k (1,1) - (3, -2)|| = \sqrt {37}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find all real numbers $k$ such that
 $|| k  (1, 1) - (3, -2) || =  \sqrt{37}.$
Ok. Am I supposed to go and manually plug in random number( which sounds terrible)
or is there another way?

I could really use some tips to get started.
Thank you!

Comment: Well, what is $||(a,b)||$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by $||(a,b)||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ then :

$$\sqrt{37}=||k(1,1)-(3,-2)||=||(k,k)+(-3+2)||=||(k-3,k+2)||=\sqrt{(k-3)^2+(k+2)^2}$$

Thus $(k-3)^2+(k+2)^2=37$

Continue it from here to find $k$